# How do I start an Amazon EC2 VM from a saved AMI using Jenkins?

Tags: api, jenkins, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a Jenkins job to spin up a VM on Amazon EC2 based on an AMI that I currently have saved. I've done my searching and can't find an easy way to do this other than through Amazon's GUI. This isn't very ideal as there are a lot of manual steps involved and it's time-consuming.

If anyone's had any luck doing this or could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Cheers,
Darwin

Comment: that's not the Jenkins' job, try with MCollective

Comment: AWS has an entire api for doing this. Look at AWS cli or AWS PowerShell depending on your platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question this should be possible using the cli, assuming you can install and configure the cli on your jenkins server you can just run the command as a shell script as part of the build.

[Create an instance with CLI.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)

The command would be something along the lines of:

```
[path to cli]/aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xyz
```

If your setup is too complicated for a single cli command, I would recommend creating a simple [cloudformation template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html).

If you are unable to install the cli, you could use any number of sdk's e.g. java to make a simple application you could run with jenkins.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Mike.

Comment: One thing to be very careful of when setting up the cli is you will need to set an access key and secret key. I assume your Jenkins is shared at least internally if not externally as well. Anybody could see you've configured the cli and start using aws commands in their builds, maliciously or just out of curiosity though they cannot actually expose your keys. Make sure you are using IAM best practises, I.e. Do not use keys for your root account, create an iam user with the least privileges you need for the task. You can always add more privileges later if you want to do other jobs.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Jenkins EC2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin)

Looking at the document it looks like you may be able to reuse your AMI. If not, you can configure it with an init script

> Next, configure AMIs that you want to launch. For this, you need to
>   find the AMI IDs for the OS of your choice. ElasticFox is a good tool
>   for doing that, but there are a number of other ways to do it. Jenkins
>   can work with any Unix AMIs. If using an Ubuntu EC2 or UEC AMI you
>   need to fill out the rootCommandPrefix and remoteAdmin fields under
>   'advanced'. Windows is currently unsupported.

Comment: I looked in to this plugin prior to posting this question and it appears to be for creating Jenkins slaves only. The AMI image that I'm trying to create instances of is running other tools and is not required (or desired) to be a Jenkins build slave.

Comment: I see. You need some sore of orchestration tool then to do that, such as http://www.ansible.com/  This looks to be a good place to start https://github.com/phips/aws-jenkins

Comment: Yeah, I need to become more familiar with Ansible, Puppet, etc. I was looking for more of a quick 'n dirty approach. It looks like the CLI solution works the best since I can just slap that inside a build job. I do agree that the proper way to do this would be with a more appropriate tool. The only reason I'm trying to shoehorn it in to Jenkins is due to the fact that every other related job is in our Jenkins CI system. Thanks for the pointers - I'll dig in to it!